# Should 'harmful' questions be answered/allowed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

You questions which could result in harm (or general disruption) to something/someone be answered?

It was thinking of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496595/how-do-i-use-reaver-to-crack-wi-fi-password).

[image]

It can be quite good (as a hacker) to test for flaws in a system etc, but not if you use it in a harmful/illegitimate way (as a cracker) - which is a potential risk.

<sub>*I'm not sure if a similar question has be asked before, is so please link it*</sub>

---

**Edit:** If I did flag this question, would this flag be appropriate for it and any similar questions?:
[image: 'It is offensive, abusive, or hate speech']

or just 'should be closed for another reason'?

---

**Another edit:** It [has been flagged as low-quality](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/291323) anyway...

Comment: My personal opinion is that it should be closed and it would be on Ubuntu Forums where there is a clear policy that we don't provide support for trying to compromise computer security.  However, I can't find anything in the Help Centre to say what site policy is.  Attacking systems to find and fix security flaws is perfectly valid if it's your own system.  But if you are trying to use someone else's WiFi for free or attack my server it's definitely not.

Comment: Thats my opinion - if its something bad, don't allow it. (Good idea with the screenshot)

Comment: Looks like at least 7 people in the community decided that it's a bad idea.

Comment: @JorgeCastro 7 people in the community decided it was a poor quality question, not that we should stop providing information that can be used for evil as well as good. The downvotes may support closure; I do not think they express the view that we shouldn't provide the public with knowledge about wifi cracking or any other controversial topic.

Comment: @EliahKagan - I thought there would be something similar - though in [the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89020/is-there-any-software-for-bypassing-the-firewall) that was talked about then, it seems a bit more popular...